# CTE to Find Sequential Backups Running in Infinite Loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, backup

I wrote below Recursive CTE query to find out Log backups in sequential order matching LastLSN to FirstLSN of next backup file. But it keeps running, and Seems its multiplying rows somewhere. I need help to figure out the problem area.

```
DECLARE @First_LSN varchar(100)
DECLARE @Last_LSN varchar(100)
DECLARE @Checkpoint_LSN varchar(100)
DECLARE @DatabaseBackup_LSN varchar(100)
DECLARE @BackupType VARCHAR(5);
DECLARE @DbName varchar(200);

SELECT @First_LSN = '3310284000022460000027', @Last_LSN = '3310301000015143400001', @Checkpoint_LSN = '3310284000022460000027', @DatabaseBackup_LSN = '3306268000010398600106'
        ,@BackupType = 'I'
        ,@DbName = 'Mosaic';


;WITH T1 AS 
(
    SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS SERVER
        ,bs.database_name
        ,bs.backup_start_date
        ,bs.backup_finish_date
        ,bs.expiration_date
        ,CASE bs.type
            WHEN 'D'
                THEN 'Database'
            WHEN 'L'
                THEN 'Log'
            WHEN 'I'
                THEN 'Differential'
            ELSE NULL
            END AS backup_type
        ,bs.backup_size
        ,bmf.logical_device_name
        ,bmf.physical_device_name
        ,bs.NAME AS backupset_name
        ,bs.description
        ,first_lsn
        ,last_lsn
        ,checkpoint_lsn
        ,database_backup_lsn
        ,is_copy_only
    FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily AS bmf
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset AS bs ON bmf.media_set_id = bs.media_set_id
    WHERE database_name = @DbName
        and is_copy_only = 0
        and (
                (@BackupType = 'L' AND bs.type = 'L' AND  first_lsn = @Last_LSN) -- When both are log
                OR 
                (@BackupType = 'I' AND bs.type = 'L' AND  cast((cast(@Last_LSN as decimal(36,0))+1) as varchar(50)) BETWEEN first_lsn and last_lsn) -- When Last was Diff, and next is Log
                OR 
                (@BackupType = 'D' AND bs.type = 'L' AND  cast((cast(@Last_LSN as decimal(36,0))+1) as varchar(50)) BETWEEN first_lsn and last_lsn) -- When Last was Diff, and next is Log
            )
    --
    UNION ALL
    --
    SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS SERVER
        ,bs.database_name
        ,bs.backup_start_date
        ,bs.backup_finish_date
        ,bs.expiration_date
        ,CASE bs.type
            WHEN 'D'
                THEN 'Database'
            WHEN 'L'
                THEN 'Log'
            WHEN 'I'
                THEN 'Differential'
            ELSE NULL
            END AS backup_type
        ,bs.backup_size
        ,bmf.logical_device_name
        ,bmf.physical_device_name
        ,bs.NAME AS backupset_name
        ,bs.description
        ,bs.first_lsn
        ,bs.last_lsn
        ,bs.checkpoint_lsn
        ,bs.database_backup_lsn
        ,bs.is_copy_only
    FROM T1 
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset AS bs ON T1.last_lsn = bs.first_lsn
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily AS bmf ON bmf.media_set_id = bs.media_set_id
    WHERE bs.database_name = @DbName
        and bs.is_copy_only = 0
        and bs.type = 'L'
)
SELECT * 
FROM T1
option ( MaxRecursion 500 )
```

[image]

Above is the screenshot of result. The second snap on top shows how the backup info starts repeating in resultset.

Comment: Just curious, why not just pull all backups, order by the competition date, and then use LAG or another window function to see if you are missing a backup?

Comment: Tip: A common debugging technique is to add a counter to the CTE, e.g. `1 as Rows` in the anchor and `Rows + 1` in the recursive query, then limit the results by adding `Rows < 10 and` to the `where` clause. Have a look at where the recursion is heading and jiggle the limit if you want to see more (or fewer) rows.

Comment: @scsimon, your suggested way is my usual method. But yesterday, our 2-node SQL Cluster went down, and we had a very weird situation where SQL Services got stuck, and were running partially on passive node as well. This lead to Log Backup jobs running on both servers at same time :) Below is sample screenshot where we see Log backups at same time (by should be serialized by default).

Comment: https://github.com/imajaydwivedi/Images/blob/master/SQLDBATools/BackupIssue.PNG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the row that your red arrow points to, the first_lsn and last_lsn are equal, so the recursive cte keeps adding that row (and its successors) over and over again. That's where the infinite loop comes from.

Comment: Thanks, @Wolfgang Kais. My eyes could not catch that :)